# I can't see the datalabels on the bars charts.js

Tags: chart.js, bar-chart

I have done many tests and I am unable to put the data in the columns, can someone help me?

I only want the numbers to appear in each bar, I can do it in other types of graphs with the **datalabel plugin**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Gráficas</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@latest/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.2.0/dist/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>
    <h1>Gráfica de Barras</h1>
    <canvas id="grafica"></canvas>
    <script src="ark.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and the ark.js. I have changed the options thousands of times and I have not been able to see the damn numbers :-(

```
const $grafica = document.querySelector("#grafica");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
const etiquetas = ["Mayo 22","Juni 22","Juli 22]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
// Podemos tener varios conjuntos de datos                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
const Continuo = {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    label: "Continuo",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    data: [0, 0, 1000],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)', // Color de fondo                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)', // Color del borde                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    borderWidth: 1,// Ancho del borde
    datalabels: {Color: '#FFCE56'},                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
};                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
const Estatico = {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    label: "Estático",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    data: [1702, 2321, 6360],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',// Color de fondo                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    borderColor: 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',// Color del borde                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    borderWidth: 1,// Ancho del borde 
    datalabels: {Color: '#FFCE56'},                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
};                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
new Chart($grafica, {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    type: 'bar',// Tipo de gráfica                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    data: {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        labels: etiquetas,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        datasets: [                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
            Continuo,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
            Estatico,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        

        ]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    },                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    options: {
        responsive: true,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        scales: {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
            yAxes: [{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                ticks: {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                    beginAtZero: true                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
            }],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        },                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since version 1.x, Datalabels plugin no longer registers itself automatically. It must be manually registered either globally or locally.

See doc: https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/getting-started.html#registration

You must register globally:

```
// Register the plugin to all charts:
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);
```

or inline

```
// OR only to specific charts:
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
  options: {
    // ...
  }
})
```

Furthermore, be aware that the options are case sensitive the the "Color" option doesn't exist but you should change in "color".